# NSUserDefaults setObject crashing in Thread

Tags: ios, crash, nsuserdefaults, ios9

I´m doing some stuff in the background. I do also try to write an object to the standard user defaults.
Since iOS 9 it is crashing.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

// calling some methods in the background
// also save a value to the user defaults
NSDate *aDate = [NSDate date];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:aDate forKey:@"date"]; // <-- crash: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

});
```

I cannot find the problem. aDate is not nil. I also tried to perform setObject: on the main thread (from the background thread), but with the same result.

The crash is sporadic!
What I´m doing wrong?

Here is the stack trace:

> Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
>
> Thread : Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos 0  libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x0000000199b0dbd0 objc_msgSend + 16 1  Foundation
>   0x0000000185ea1eb4 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification)
>   willChangeValueForKey:] + 324 2  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000185090994 _CFPreferencesSetValueWithContainer + 168 3 
>   Foundation                     0x0000000185eb9138
>   -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 56 4  AIR                            0x00000001000f201c -[ServerSyncAgent syncUnsyncedEntities]
>   (ServerSyncAgent.m:212) 5  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x000000019a2e97b0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 6 
>   libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019a2e9770
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 16 7  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019a2f7bb0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140 8 
>   libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019a2f734c
>   _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112 9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000019a4fd478 _pthread_wqthread + 1092

Comment: Are you getting crash on that same line ? I think the crash is happening from some other place. I've used the above code and didn't get any crash.

Comment: can you try inserting the string with the same key ?

Comment: I´m getting the crash also in other methods, where I use NSUserDefaults setObject: The crash is always in the line setObject:

Comment: @Matt Post a full stack trace. Show more code.

Comment: @Nikolai just added the stack trace. If I uncomment the line in code, it will crash again, where NSUserDefaults setObject: is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/):

> The NSUserDefaults class is thread-safe.

The posted code is fine. Your error is elsewhere.

**Edit:** The stack points out the source of your bug:

Somewhere else in your code you (or some 3rd party library) are adding a KVO observer to `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`. Yet, `NSUserDefaults` is not KVO compliant, so you can't add observers.

If there's need to react on changes to user defaults you have to use `NSNotificationCenter` and register for `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification`.

**2nd Edit:** Not sure when this changed but in modern iOS and macOS `NSUserDefaults` is Key-Value observable. The same documentation as linked above now clearly states:

> You can use key-value observing to register observers for specific keys of interest in order to be notified of all updates to a local defaults database. For more details, see Key-Value Observing Programming Guide.

Comment: I know that it is thread safe. But the crash is only happening if I call NSUserDefaults also in other methods.

Comment: @Matt As I said, there's no problem in the code and information you provided. The crash you are experiencing results from another place in your code. Without more information there's no way we can help you.

Comment: it is really strange. I didn't found any code that observes [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]. I have also removed all libraries. But is only appears in a background thread. If I call it on the main thread, it works. What can I try to find the problem? NSZombieEnabled does not help, because is I enable it, the Crash does not appear.

Comment: @Matt Set a symbolic breakpoint in `-[NSObject addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:]`, add a condition `(BOOL)[$arg1 isKindOfClass:[NSUserDefaults class]]` and run your app. When the debugger stops it'll point you to the offending code.

Comment: Thank you so much! There was an observer I did not found. It should only be used for the Mac library but was also used for iOS.

Comment: @Matt Are you aware that observing NSUserDefaults is a mistake, even under Mac OS?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Why shouldn't NSUserDefaults be KVO 'compliant'? It works for me and in the interface of NSUserDefaults KVO is also mentioned! But of course the observer itself could cause a crash...

Comment: @JensSchwarzer Back in the days, `NSUserDefaults` has not supported KVO for a long time. This was silently changed in some Foundation release — not sure which one. Nowadays Apple makes this more and more public, with the latest OS releases even promoting to use KVO for interprocess synchronization.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe OK thanks - I was just puzzled to this statement in fairly new post :)